# set byte if value cant fit

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I want to set a byte at max or min value, if the value I try to assign is greater. Is there a better way to do it, instead of checking with if statements?

example:

```
int[] arr = new int[128]; // assume int array is filled with random values
byte[] arr2 = new byte[128]; 

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i] > 127) {
    arr2[i] = 127;
  } else if (arr[i] < -128) {
    arr2[i] = -128;
  } else {
    arr2[i] = arr[i];
  }
}
```

is there a way to replace the if/else statement with bitwise operations?
Or is there a smarter/faster way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could chain `Math.min(int, int)` and `Math.max(int, int)` calls. Like,

```
arr2[i] = (byte) Math.min(127, Math.max(-128, arr[i]));
```

If `arr[i]` is less than `-128` that will take `-128`. If the result of that is greater than `127` it will take `127`. Which should cover all of your cases.

Comment: I'm curious how would the compiler would optimize that chaining (which are branches too) compared to the original manual branches.

Comment: @Matthieu I tied it and and for 100,000 element arrays they are about the same. for larger arrays Math becomes faster. For small arrays ~1000 elements if/else is twice as fast but in nanoseconds.

Comment: *Often, the way to write fast code in Java applications is to write dumb code -- code that is straightforward, clean, and follows the most obvious object-oriented principles.* - [The Developer Insight Series, Part 1: Write Dumb Code](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/javase/devinsight-1.html)

Comment: @Elliott I wish they taught that in schools: especially because "dumb code" is a lot easier for the compiler to optimize into efficient code (not only in Java btw).